# How to center gridster.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gridster

I have been playing with Gridster.js, but for the life of me, I can't seem to make the grid centered, its always left justified, I have tried and tried, but maybe I am missing something..

I have made a jsfiddle that has the basic of my grid, Im hoping someone can work it out and help me center it, please :)

```
.gridster {
    background: #004756;
       margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: .8;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .6s;
    -o-transition: opacity .6s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .6s;
    transition: opacity .6s;
    text-align: center;
}
.gridster > * {
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transition: height .4s;
    -moz-transition: height .4s;
    -o-transition: height .4s;
    -ms-transition: height .4s;
    transition: height .4s;
}

.gridster .gs_w{
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
        background: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.ready .gs_w:not(.preview-holder) {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s, left .3s, top .3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s, left .3s, top .3s;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s, left .3s, top .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s, left .3s, top .3s;
}

.ready .gs_w:not(.preview-holder) {
    -webkit-transition: opacity .3s, left .3s, top .3s, width .3s, height .3s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .3s, left .3s, top .3s, width .3s, height .3s;
    -o-transition: opacity .3s, left .3s, top .3s, width .3s, height .3s;
    transition: opacity .3s, left .3s, top .3s, width .3s, height .3s;
}

.gridster .preview-holder {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.gridster .player-revert {
    z-index: 10!important;
    -webkit-transition: left .3s, top .3s!important;
    -moz-transition: left .3s, top .3s!important;
    -o-transition: left .3s, top .3s!important;
    transition:  left .3s, top .3s!important;
}

.gridster .dragging {
    z-index: 10!important;
    -webkit-transition: all 0s !important;
    -moz-transition: all 0s !important;
    -o-transition: all 0s !important;
    transition: all 0s !important;
}

.gridWrapper {
   width: 100%;

    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.gridAlignerWrapper {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.gridAligner {
    width: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
        }

body {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: x-small;
    color: #666666;
    text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
}

ul, ol {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0 auto;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;


}

h1 {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400; 
}

h3 {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white; 
}

/* Uncomment this if you set helper : "clone" in draggable options */
/*.gridster .player {
  opacity:0;
}*/
```

https://jsfiddle.net/036qutd9/4/

Thanks

Comment: It is centered...but it's also 100% wide....not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: what do you mean its centered? when I look at the jsfiddle (and my live site) the boxes are all left justified, there is lots of unused space on the right, as my grid is only 5 columns, I want the 5 column grid to be centered to its colored wrapper..

Comment: Then you need to set a width on the containing div so the `margin:auto` will work to center it inside the wrapper.

Comment: ok, i still can't get that to work how i expected, can you updated the jsfiddle with what you mean so I can see it working?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paulie_D, I managed to work it out and get it centered :)

```
.gridster {
    width: 730px;
    background: #004756;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    opacity: .8;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s;
    -moz-transition: opacity .6s;
    -o-transition: opacity .6s;
    -ms-transition: opacity .6s;
    transition: opacity .6s;
    text-align: center;
}
.gridster > * {
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transition: height .4s;
    -moz-transition: height .4s;
    -o-transition: height .4s;
    -ms-transition: height .4s;
    transition: height .4s;
}
```